# How to Exclude Files and Folders from Volume Shadow Copy (VSS) Backups

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, volume-shadow-copy, vss

I've been using Volume Shadow Copy (VSS) to create backups of my files and folders. However, I've encountered a situation :

I need to ***exclude*** specific files and folders from **Microsoft built-in Volume shadow Copy** to save storage space and time. Since VSS is enabled for the drive, there are few unwanted folder / files that are being backed up by VSS and If I delete them all other shadow copies of other files (of previous versions) might be lost.

Here are a few details about my setup:

Operating System: Windows Server 2012 R2
Volume Shadow Copy:
Provider name: 'Microsoft File Share Shadow Copy provider'
Provider type: Fileshare Version: 1.0.0.1

Provider name: 'Microsoft Software Shadow Copy provider 1.0'
Provider type: System Version: 1.0.0.7

I would appreciate it if someone could walk me through the process of excluding files and folders from VSS backups. What are the steps involved, and are there any best practices I should be aware of?.

I did search in Google and found some articles, but none of them solved my issue.

Here are few links that I have gone through.

This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/vss/excluding-files-from-shadow-copies#:%7E:text=The-,FilesNotToSnapshot,-registry%20key%20is) provides FilesNotToSnapshot registry key can be used to exclude files but it is developers specific.

Answer (score 0):

If you use drive imaging software that already has implemented excluding folders and files through VSS, you can use that Registry hack for your purposes. Note, though, the *caveat* from Macrium, linked below: "Although this can be useful in removing unnecessary files from images and clones the functionality isn't 100% reliable."

- [Macrium Reflect](https://knowledgebase.macrium.com/display/KNOW72/How+to+exclude+files+from+a+Disk+Image) uses `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\BackupRestore\FilesNotToSnapshotMacriumImage`.
- Other software might have a GUI to to create the exclude list. For example, [O&O DiskImge 11](https://docs.oo-software.com/en/oodiskimage-11/settings-for-drive-imaging-11/exclude-files-from-an-image-11) provides a dialog for eliminating files in an image. This *might* use VssWriter to implement this behind the scenes.

Another option is to use compression when imaging a drive, since space is at a premium. Many of the imaging tools have variable compression levels -- higher compression may slow writing.

**Test reliability when making any change in established imaging procedures.** *Verify* the image, and mount to check that files are accessible. An employer for whom I worked had *daily* backups made, but on the day he needed old code, he found *none* of the images readable.